# how to pull docker images in a fast way. It takes too much of time just to download 50mb of image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to pull docker redis image. But its taking more than 1 hour just to download 50mb of image. Can someone please share their idea on how to download the image in a faster way.

Comment: What about a faster internet connection?

Comment: Which redis image are you trying to pull? Do you have any firewall or anti-virus filtering which could be slowing down the pull? You could try using a remote server (e.g., free AWS tier) and compare.

Answer (score 1):

The [latest redis alpine images](https://imagelayers.io/?images=redis:3.0.6-alpine) should not be 50Mb.

But anyway, a faster way to download an image is to download its Dockerfile (and the Dockerfile of its parent image, and so on).
However, the re-build step *locally* of all the layers might in itself be time-consuming, as noted [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38814613/how-to-pull-docker-images-in-a-fast-way-it-takes-too-much-of-time-just-to-downl/38815120#comment78857498_38815120) by [Chris Kitching](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2283319/chris-kitching).

The alpine one is easy to build (see [Dockerfile](https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/blob/45ba65c1116aaf668f7ab5f2b3ae2ef4b00738be/versions/library-3.4/Dockerfile)), and is based on a [`rootfs.tar.gz`](https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/blob/45ba65c1116aaf668f7ab5f2b3ae2ef4b00738be/versions/library-3.4/rootfs.tar.gz) if only 2.2 Mb.

The Dockerfile for each of those image layers is but a few Kb.

Comment: I'd dispute the generate statement "the fastest way to download an image is to download its dockerfile and rebuild it locally". Many Dockerfiles do time-consuming operations like compiling software, something which generally takes _far_ longer than downloading it pre-built.

Comment: @ChrisKitching Good point. I have amended the answer to make that clearer, with a reference to your comment for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

We are facing the same issue at our end. It seems that the issue lies with Cloudfare using which the images are being provided onto dockerhub. The issue still persists as the latest comment on the issue over github is just 8days ago.
https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/1675

Not sure by when would the issue be fixed.